# Get the checked value of my checkbox

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="right">
        <label class="input-control tiny-checkbox" onclick="">
            <input type="checkbox" value="0"/>
            <span class="helper"></span>
        </label>
    </td>
    ...
```

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("table tbody tr td").click(function () {
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

    if (col == 0) {
        // col checkbox -> highlight the line (on/off)
        var checked = $(this).children(':checkbox').is(':checked');
```

The checked var is never true even if the ckeckbox is checked. I don't know why.

Any idea?

Comment: Just a sidenote: `var col = $(this).index(); var row = $(this).closest("tr").index();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `find` inside of `children` because children checks in direct child element,
not in grand child.

```
  var checked = $(this).find(':checkbox').is(':checked');
```

Comment: Right, `children` is rarely needed, and 100% not needed when querying on a single element. `find` is always gonna be faster anyway. So I'd say use `find` as much as possible and `children` only when strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find()` method instead of `children()` since the checkbox is not a direct child of the `td`

```
$("table tbody tr td").click(function () {
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

    if (col == 0) {
        // col checkbox -> highlight the line (on/off)
        var checked = $(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MShgq/